# Error msg to user in django

Tags: html, django

I have an html page where user insert data and click on ok button.
When button click a python function is checking if everything is ok and in that case update my DB.

In one of the cases when a check is false I want to pop up a msg to the user letting him know the operation faild.

What I did is:

```
  if a<b:
     return render(request, 'main/error.html')
```

and in error.html I puted the error details.

However this is extrimly inconvinet as the page is changing to error.html.
I want to give this error msg as Messege box or something like that... so that it stays on the same page.

The thing is that from `views.py` I can't access the html page and ask it to pop a msg.

How can I pop up a msg when a condition is false?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) in order to display a message on your page:

> Quite commonly in web applications, you need to display a one-time notification message (also known as “flash message”) to the user after processing a form or some other types of user input.
>
> For this, Django provides full support for cookie- and session-based messaging, for both anonymous and authenticated users. The messages framework allows you to temporarily store messages in one request and retrieve them for display in a subsequent request (usually the next one). Every message is tagged with a specific *level* that determines its priority (e.g., *info*, *warning*, or *error*).

There is extensive documentation and examples on the link provided.

EDIT: Example

Summary of settings (*settings.py*):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    ...
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': True,
        },
    },
]
```

In a view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

if a < b:
    messages.warning("a is less than b.")
```

In a template (example using bootstrap3):

```
{% if messages %}
    <div class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Can you show an example of this in a real program? they are saying add this, add that but it doesn't work at the end. I don't understand how it solves my problem... they are telling to add "if messege" to my templete... but the templete is loaded on start... on start there wont be any messages.... it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: @aayushdagra: What have you tried? What error do you have if you said "it doesn't work"? To me it sounds like a perfect solution to your problem. You can also just google "django messaging framework" it will give you tons of examples.

Comment: @aayushdagra I would agree with Shang Wang, what have you tried? If you read the documentation it is pretty straightforward. Nevertheless, I added an example for your convenience and I hope it helps.